# How to intercept an eventhandler in javascript?

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, event-listener, firefox-developer-tools

Let's say I have a simple webpage with only a small js file:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log("click event fired");
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    console.log("keypress event fired");
});
```

How to use the firefox developer console to:

1. Overwrite the addEventListener function so I can log which type it was listening to?
2. After logging execute the original function code

Right now I have this:

```
Object.defineProperty(Document.prototype, "addEventListener", {
    value: function () {
        console.log("addEventListener of type ...? was fired");
        // execute original function
    }
});
```

Whenever the document is clicked, the output should be:

*addEventListener of type click was fired*
*click event fired*

Or when a key is pressed:

*addEventListener of type keypress was fired*
*keypress event fired*

edit: Using the debugger would not solve my problem. I would like to know which eventlisteners are present on a site, and automate this for a long list of sites.

Comment: What do you mean with *addEventListener of type click was fired*? What types with exception of left mouse button clicks do you expect here?

Comment: @tacoshy In this example I only expect mouse clicks, but I would like to use it in a scenario with multiple eventListeners for different types like mousemove and keypress

Comment: Really you shouldn't have to monkeypatch `addEventListener` just for inspection. Use https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/page_inspector/how_to/examine_event_listeners/index.html and https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/set_event_listener_breakpoints/index.html

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the links, I was not aware that is possible. Anyway, I would like to use the data that I get by intercepting the listeners in my code. So I'm still looking for a solution in js

Comment: @TimMG Instead of "intercepting" listeners, you should just add your own extra listener

Comment: @Bergi Adding my own listeners would not fix to my problem. What I'm doing here is seeing if there are any eventlisteners, and if so: which ones? And how many of them? Making my own listener would not solve the first question

Comment: @TimMG What problem is it that your code is trying to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `value` is the new value of the `addEventListener()` function, not the callback function that's provided which gets invoked. In order to log each time the event occurs, you need to modify the callback as well, which can be done by calling the original `addEventListener()` function and then providing your own callback that performs the logging. Below I'm also updating `EventTarget.prototype`, which allows you to intercept the `addEventListener` on all elements that extend EventTarget:

```js
const proto = EventTarget.prototype;
const _addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
Object.defineProperty(proto, "addEventListener", {
  value: function (type, fn, ...rest) {       
      _addEventListener.call(this, type, function(...args) {
        console.log(`addEventListener of type ${type} was fired`);
        return fn.apply(this, args);
      }, ...rest);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  console.log("keydown");
});

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("clicked");
});
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
```

---

Note, by providing your own wrapper around the original callback function, using `removeEventListener()` won't work as expected, to handle this (and another edge case where the same function reference is passed to `addEventListener()`), one idea to handle this it to keep a Map of the functions added as event handlers and reuse the custom callback when needed:

```js
const proto = EventTarget.prototype;
const _addEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.addEventListener;
const _removeEventListener = EventTarget.prototype.removeEventListener;
const callbacks = new WeakMap();
Object.defineProperty(proto, "addEventListener", {
  value: function(type, fn, ...rest) {
    const cb = callbacks.get(fn) ?? function(...args) {
      console.log(`addEventListener of type ${type} was fired`);
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    }
    callbacks.set(fn, cb);
    _addEventListener.call(this, type, cb, ...rest);
  }
});

Object.defineProperty(proto, "removeEventListener", {
  value: function(type, fn, ...rest) {
    const cb = callbacks.get(fn);
    _removeEventListener.call(this, type, cb, ...rest);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {
  console.log("keydown");
});

const mouseover = () => console.log("hover");
para.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseover);

btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("clicked, removing event listener");
  para.removeEventListener("mouseover", mouseover);
});
```

```css
p {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<p id="para">Hover me</p>
<button id="btn">Remove hover event listener</button>
```

Comment: I love your answer. Too bad OP probably just didn't know how to use a debugger.

Comment: @pkExec Thank you :) - Yes agreed, using the browser's debugger is definitely a better option than this (I'm sure there are some edge cases I haven't thought about where the above will break), a browsers dev tools would be much more robust

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer. Is it correct that this code has to be run before the eventListeners get added or they will not be intercepted? Also, I would like to add that just using the debugger would not suffice. I will clarify this in the question

Comment: Hi @TimMG, urs that is right, this would need to execute before the event listens are added. Getting that timing right might be a bit tricky

Answer (score 0):

The DevTools provide a way to log events without having to change the code.

To do that go to the [Debugger](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/). In there, there is an *Event Listener Breakpoints* pane, which let's you set breakpoints for many different kinds of events. To only [log the events](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/debugger/set_event_listener_breakpoints/index.html#logging-on-events) instead of stopping the script execution at the line of the event listener function, you have to check the *Log* option in the header of the pane.

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints pane in Firefox DevTools' Debugger listening for the 'click' event and having the Log option enabled to log the events to the Console]

When an event listener is hit, the event is then logged to the Console including a link to the source code, which looks like this:

[image: 'click' events being logged to the Console]

What you *cannot* do at the moment (as of Firefox 118) is setting a condition for the events you are listening. Therefore, I've created a [feature request to add conditional event breakpoints](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1859378).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use the `Document.prototype.addEventListener` to achieve your goal.

example:

```
const originalAddEventListener = Document.prototype.addEventListener;

Document.prototype.addEventListener = function (type, listener, options) {
    console.log(`addEventListener of type ${type} was fired`);
    originalAddEventListener.call(this, type, listener, options);
};

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    console.log("click event fired");
});

document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    console.log("keypress event fired");
});
```